# CSS to display only part of the <select> or drop down list

Tags: html, css, styles, usability

I have the following drop down list:

```
<select>
   <option value="+1">+1</option>
   <option value="+93">Afghanistan (+93)</option>
   <option value="+355">Albania (+355)</option>
   <option value="+213">Algeria (+213)</option>
   <option value="+1">American Samoa (+1)</option>
   ...
</select>
```

However, space is limited to me; I can't display the entire name of the country. I want to display what's relevant to the user once selected. So I opted to display only the country code by rearranging the option's text and the country to the following:

```
<select style="width: 60px;">
    <option value="+1">+1</option>
    <option value="+93">+93 - Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="+355">+355 - Albania</option>
    <option value="+213">+213 - Algeria</option>
    <option value="+1">+1 - American Samoa</option>
    ...
</select>
```

And by setting a width on the select. However, the problem is... I have just lost usability. Now the user can no longer use the keyboard to type the name of his country and quickly jump to it.

So, how can I solve this, without javascript? Can I rearrange the select list to the previous list and clip it with CSS to display the last portion of the option?

Comment: I didn't understand loosing space or `limited space`.

Comment: The space or more specifically, the width <select> takes up when the width is not explicitly set. (In this case, it'll take up at least the width of the longest option's text.)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `:before` pseudoelement to show the prefix, e.g. http://jsbin.com/erazar/1/edit

CSS

```
option:before {
   content: "(" attr(value) ")";
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: .5em;    
}
```

HTML

```
<select>
   <option value="+93">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="+355">Albania</option>
   <option value="+213">Algeria</option>
   <option value="+1">American Samoa</option>
</select>
```

With this approach the prefix will appear in front of the option and your user will be able to choose the State typing its name by the keyboard

Comment: This is not working for me, mate. I'm seeing the country's name when selected, not its value.

Comment: this style doesn't affect the current option: open the select, you should see the list of countries with the prefix (tested on `Fx22`)

Comment: I hear you, I have selected American Samoa and I'm still seeing American Samoa as the selected text and its respective width, not +1.

Comment: Ah... I just tested it with Firefox and I see what you did. However, it doesn't work on Chrome and IE11. Thus, it's a no go. :(

Comment: Sorry, but without javascript this is the the better idea I had. Unfortunately I tested just in the only browser that supports pseudoelements for the option element :\